# Via Code - Change the order of Umbraco Nodes in Back office

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

During the Gathering Node data event, I want to run some code and based on the result I want to change the order of nodes in the Umbraco back office.

Is this possible? I'm using V6

Answer (score 0):

In code there is a sort order method against Document

```
Document doc = new Document(<nodeId>);
doc.SortOrder = <int>;
```

This manipulates the database tables including cmsContentXml & UmbracoNode:

[image]

[image]